# Download browserify bundle from node.js

Tags: node.js, express, browserify

I'm trying to develop node.js app with express.js. One of the thing which I try to implement is a function to serve generated by browserify bundle js file. What I would like to do is to use maven-download-plugin to download that file and put into my repository (it's java app). I know that his is a bit complicated but that's how it's look like. I can generate bundle with browserify using code:

```
    browserify("./path/myjs.js", {
           gzip : true
        });
        b.transform("hbsfy");
        b = b.bundle({standalone: 'bundle'});
```

However I cannot find any information how to write that information to the public/bundle.js and how to serve it when for example path /bundle.js will be requested.
Any ideas how can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you generate the bundle when the app is deployed? Bundling on the fly seems to be a pretty bad idea.

Comment: on the production of course it will be bundled when app is deployed, but during development I need to download it using maven

Answer (score 0):

Well, why don't you just use static module for express?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

To write bundle to the file, just stream it...

```
var fs = require('fs');
var ws = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/public/bundle.js');
b.bundle({standalone: 'bundle'}).pipe(ws);
```

---

Or you can do it completely on-fly avoiding file-system and streaming directly to client...

```
app.get('/bundle.js', function(req, res, next) {
    b.bundle({standalone: 'bundle'}).pipe(res);
});
```